# Why the filtered website is pinged?

Tags: ping, route-filter

My ISP has filtered some websites and i can't access them by my web browser . But i can ping that websites . How could be this happen ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ping uses ICMP whereas web browsing uses HTTP (TCP port 80) and HTTPS (TCP port 443). It sounds like the two TCP ports have been blocked but ICMP has not.

Comment: Then we can say that the filtering is done in transport layer , not in network layer . Is this conclusion true ?

Comment: Exactly. You're spot on.